# Adding an Email Validation to Contact form

Tags: php, html, validation

I created a Contact form using HTML and PHP.

i managed to make the fields mandatory using "reguired" in the HTML. 
however, right now even when i add anything in the Email fild, the submit button works.

i prefer to do this with HTML rather than PHP.

- my skills in coding is very limited.

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="container contactform center">
<h2 class="text-center  wowload fadeInUp">Get in touch</h2>
  <div class="row wowload fadeInLeftBig">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <form action="/assets/bootstrap/php/emailscript.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" required >
          <input type="text" placeholder="Company" name="Company" required >
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" required >
          <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="Subject" required >
          <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Message" name="Message" required ></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
        </form>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP Code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Name']))
{
    $name=$_POST['Name'] ;
    $company=$_POST['Company'] ;
    $from=$_POST['Email'] ;
    $message=$_POST['Message'] ;
    $to="contact@ananasmedia.com" ;
    $subject="Website Contact Form" ;

    mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $from . $name .  $company ) ;

    echo "Sent" ;

}
?>
```

I want to submit only with valid email form (email@domain.TLD)

Comment: Do you want to do this on client-side (html) or server-side (php)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't specify what have you tried so far. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: validate from where client/server

Comment: What for a validatioon? It the email contains a @ and stuff like that? For that you can use REGEX. 
Just Google for it, there are tousands of examples.

Comment: Have you not searched for this first and to resolve it yourself? There is a lot of stuff out there, believe me. Your question shows no effort on your part whatsoever.

Comment: my coding skills is very limited, i tried nothing yet, i want a simple email validation, i'll try what you suggested here and update

Comment: [UPDATE] finally i managed to validate the email through HTML   'code'<input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid e-mail address')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try

1. `required` in html

   ```
   <input .... name="Name" required>
   ```
2. `empty` in PHP

   ```
   if (empty($name) || empty($company) || empty($from) ||empty($message)) {
       # empty
       echo "Empty....";
   } else {
       # send mail
       mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name . $company . $email) ;
   }
   ```

Or can use validation or JavaScript too

> **beware about [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

[Example of contact form validation](https://www.formget.com/php-contact-form/)

Comment: the "reguired" in the HTML actually helped, thanks. but yet i need to validate the email to a "Real" email like test@email.com

Comment: @Balagosh you can validate email only. not real email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for email :

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

and for other input fields use

```
if(!isset($_POST['fieldName'])) {
    // throw exception or return error
}
```

Comment: `isset()` will return true even if it's empty. It only checks if the variable is set, which is always the case upon form submit. `empty()` also checks if there's actually a value in it.

Comment: Yes `empty()` function can be used to avoid blank or null value

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Email']) && $_POST['Email']!='')
{
    $name=$_POST['Name'] ;
    $company=$_POST['Company'] ;
    $from=$_POST['Email'] ;
    $message=$_POST['Message'] ;
    $to="contact@website.com" ;
    $subject="Website Contact Form" ;

    mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name . $company . $email) ;
    echo "Sent" ;
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Please insert email address."; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['Email']) && $_POST['Email']!='')` that can be cut down to just an `!empty()`.